# AngularJS UiBoostrap Accordion. Controller 'uibAccordion', required by directive 'uibAccordionGroup', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I'm working on an AngularJS app.

In my index.html, at the end of my body tag I declare this :

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

I include 'ui.bootstrap' in my angular.module

And in my html, I try to use uib-accordion

```
<div id="Help" uib-accordion-group is-open="main.openHelp">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
        <span >
            Help
        </span>            
        <span>
            <i class="pull-right fa" ng-click="main.openHelp = !main.openHelp" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': main.openHelp, 'fa-chevron-left': !main.openHelp}"></i>                    
        </span>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
             Useless Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working fine, I can open / close it etc...

The problem is that I have an error logged  :
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=uibAccordion&p1=uibAccordionGroup

I dont understand what I should do to solve this.

By the way, since I use multiple times uib accordion in this page, this error is logged multiple times. ( I have different  `<div uib-accordion-group ></div>`tags )

Comment: have you added the angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']); in your module

Comment: Is there a difference with what I said ? I said I included 'ui.bootstrap' in my angular.module, which means I did :  
var app = angular.module('myModule',['ui.bootstrap'])

Do I have to include this module in another one ?

Comment: You only need to include <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script> no need of 
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
Can you check that

Comment: Same thing if i comment this line, but i think i need this for the rest of the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the error gives you a hint

> Controller 'uibAccordion', required by directive 'uibAccordionGroup', can't be found!

The hint is with the word `required`. In AngularJS, [directives can define a requirement to be included inside other directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-), and if these to-be-father directives don't exist then you will get an error, as you got.

In your case, the directive `uibAccordionGroup` needs to be nested inside the `uibAccordion` which you didn't define inside your HTML.

This is how it supposed to look like

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime"> <!-- pay attention to this line -->
    <div id="Help" uib-accordion-group is-open="main.openHelp">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
        <span >
            Help
        </span>            
        <span>
        <i class="pull-right fa" ng-click="main.openHelp = !main.openHelp" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': main.openHelp, 'fa-chevron-left': !main.openHelp}"></i>                    
        </span>
    </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                 Useless Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Also @Nair Athul is right, you should either include

`<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js">`

or

`<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js">`

not both!

Comment: It worked. But now heading is behaving differently. I had buttons on it which were doing something else than opening/closing the accordion. Now, everything in the heading makes my accordion close/open when i click on it. I managed to put them away so I'm fine

Comment: `Now, everything in the heading makes my accordion close/open when i click on it.`, that's actually the expected behavior.
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3299